# Does the browser persistently cache compiled versions of script elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In a web app that allows users to play with javascript I require them to have a `function main()` in their "program". There's a "run" button, and an "edit" button. When you press "run" text from a `<textarea>` is used to create a script block and insert it into the DOM. Then `main()` is called.

I catch `window.onerror` to display errors to the user. This generally works OK. If there is no `main()`, an appropriate error message is shown.

When you press "edit", the script block is set to blank (`script.text = '';`),and removed from the DOM.

Testing, I noticed that if I had "program" consisting of just:

```
function main() { printLn('main here'); }
```

it worked as expected, but when I changed that to:

```
function moon() { printLn('moon here'); }
```

instead of getting a message saying `main() not defined`, it still worked as before, despite the fact that the script block had the "moon" text. This continued to happen if I gave each created script block a distinctive ID, and if I changed the script block type to `text/plain` before removing it.

The problem occurs in current Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. You can see what happens [here](http://britseyeview.com/jswb/)

Answer (score 4):

The functions are still defined, even if you remove the script that defined it.

This is in stark contrast to CSS, where removing or modifying a stylesheet will remove or update the styles on the page accordingly.

There's a good reason for that, and that is that CSS is designed to be easily re-evaluated when changes are made. JavaScript on the other hand is far too complex for the browser to be able to understand what "removing a script" actually does.

So, provided you have run one function with `main()`, it will continue to exist even if you then delete it.

My suggestion would be to create a closure to run your script. You can do this with something like...

```
var input = "........"; // user's input
var runner = "if( typeof main === 'undefined') {"+
    "showErrorMessage('No main() defined');"+ // or whatever your error function is
  "} else { main(); }";
var func = new Function("(function() {"+input+runner+"})()");
func();
```

It's always worth noting that the global scope can still be accessed, such as if the user forgets to `var` their local variables, or if they outright access `window.something`. So long as it's only being run on the user's own machine, this isn't much of an issue, but if people can share their codes with others then you will need to be much more careful.

Comment: Dynamically defining and calling a function to call main does not help. Main is a function in the code the user has typed. The dynamically created function calls it, and thereafter typeof main returns 'function'. I'm wondering if the best approach is to uniqueify the main function name by tagging on an incrementing integer, then reload the page when it gets up to 100 or some arbitrary number so as to clear out the garbage.

Comment: @SteveTeale The code in this answer creates a closure that `main` will be defined and called in. It won't exist outside the closure, so there is no need to ensure uniqueness or increment it.

Comment: The user has created a script block where the function main() was defined. For the page to work, that function needs to be called.

Comment: I've been looking for the solution in the wrong direction. Just checking the user's code with a simple regex test and telling user she hasn't defined main works fine.